# Delete empty files

Tags: python

I'd like to remove files which is empty.

```
import os
book_list = ['Automate the Boring Stuff with Python.pdf',
 'OReilly.Think.Python.2nd.Edition.2015.12.pdf',
 'Apress-Magnus_Lie_Hetland-python_algorithms.pdf',
 'Python for Data Analysis - 2012.pdf']
for book in book_list:
    if os.path.getsize(book) == 0:
        os.remove(book)
```

It seems not pythonic because of the boolean comparsion `==`.

How to accomplish such a task in an alternative way?

Comment: you can use `if not os.path.getsize(book)` but what you've done is not necessarily unpythonic.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: == is not Boolean , it’s equality ie `__eq__`   I don’t think there is anything unpythonic about using it

Comment: I prefer `== 0` here. You're getting an `int` containing the file size, and you want to know if the size equals zero. I don't like `not` in this case, because I use multiple languages and have trouble keeping track of which ones regard `0` as "falsy" or "truthy". Python considers `0` to be falsy, so `not 0` is `True`, but Ruby considers _any_ number, `0` included, to be _truthy_, so `not 0` is `false`!

Answer (score 2):

That is correct usage of the equality operator. If you want to be 'fancy' you can use the code provided by sam-pyt:

```
if not os.path.getsize(book)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import glob
    indir="/Users/fzf058/IAMRoleRemovalfolder/IAMRoleRemovalFiles/iamroleremovalfiles/42618files/implementfolder"

os.chdir(indir)
fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")

for filename in fileList:
    if os.stat(filename).st_size==0:
        os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: this is not appearing correctly with the intended indents

Comment: Thank you NobodyNada!  This was my first post.

Comment: No problem!  You can format code by prepending four spaces before each line (or by highlighting the code and clicking the "code" button in the editor).  See [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21b4885a-e080-41b2-8999-d92330bc42e8/view-source) as an example; more information is in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).